# Xpath - issue, detection of element using firebug

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have one doubt. Whenever I copy xpath from Firebug and try to use it in my selenium script, the functionality does not work. Or I get this error that unable to locate the element. But, certainly when I try to write expression and execute the same code snippet, it works fine. Why is it so, is there some problem with Firebug which is one of the popular tool.
suggestions welcomed.

Comment: You will find more Automation Testing Programmers on this site: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons for the firebug generated XPath not to work in selenium.

Most common are two:

- an element you are trying to find is *not yet present in the DOM* - this could happen when the page is not completely loaded, or is loaded asynchronously
- there are `iframe` elements on a page. If you need to find and element inside an `iframe`, you need to *switch to it* first

Also, don't blindly trust the XPath generated by Firebug - most of the time it would not be the most reliable expression. If possible, operate `id` and `class` attributes and don't start your XPath expression from the root HTML element - make it relative (using `//`).

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is not with the Xpath you are using,
First check where your element is located,
The reason here is your element is not visible to the driver,
The question here is why the element is not visible,
Work on this,
And Do provide the html code in your question so that it will be more helpful to resolve the issue quickly,

Comment: hi I have used Firepath as an addon with Firebug. The issue seems resolved now. Firepath, I found very useful.